# A way to center TD in TR?

Tags: html, html-table, alignment

I am working on HTML email and trying to center a green TD in a white TR so that there's a 20px white margin on the left and right of the green box.

I tried setting TD width for the green portion and setting margin 0 auto but the green just expands to the width of the TR.

Tried putting in 2 more TDs to push the green TD into the center and that didn't work either.

Including the code snippet, am having trouble with the TR that has #a6d971.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" height="" bgcolor="" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <img width="600" height="23" padding="0" src="assets/graphic_scalloped_top.png" alt="" style="display: block;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#fff" height="75">
            <td valign="top" style="text-align:center;">
                <p style="margin:0; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; color:#545d69; font-size: 24px; text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">
                    Regular sales happen every day
                </p>
                <p style="margin:0; padding-bottom: 3px; padding-top: 3px; color:#4bc1d6; font-size: 16px; text-align:center; font-family: Arial, Helvetica;">
                    9am - 11pm
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr bgcolor="#fff" height="75" padding="10">
            <td bgcolor="#000" width="20"></td>
            <td bgcolor="#a6d971" width="300" style="margin: 10;">
            </td>
            <td bgcolor="#000" width="20"></td>
        </tr>



        <tr bgcolor="#fff">
            <td valign="top">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" align="center" width="100%" bgcolor="#fff" style="">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td height="80" style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; color: #555; background:url('assets/graphic_9am.png') no-repeat; background-position: 10% center; padding:10px; margin:0;">
                                <h3>Nine @ Nine</h3>
                                <p>Fuel up! Dresses, tunics and other items including:</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>




                        <tr>

                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td style="margin: 0 auto;">
                <img width="600" height="23" padding="0" src="assets/graphic_scalloped_bottom.png" alt="" style="display: block;" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: For all the problems that email clients have with CSS … they are generally pretty good when all you want to do is centre a box and set some colours. Don't abuse a table for this.

Comment: Do you have a picture to illustrate?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're using tables?

Comment: @Purmou, as much as it pains me, tables and inline-CSS is still the best way to develop for emails. =/

Comment: yea, that's why I have to use tables :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch to DIV's and CSS, most emails client supports styles pretty well, you can use a DIV inside your TD element, it'll be easy to center or do other things you might want.

For Example

```
<tr style="background-color: white;">
  <td  style="background-color: green;">
    <div style="background-color: purple; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px;">Content Here</div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Also note if you use DIV's you can also avoid tables.

Comment: awesome thanks, this works perfectly. I thought I had tried this one, but it kept messing up the rest of the content when I tried it.

Comment: Btw, I didn't know we could use DIVs and CSS in email clients now. Last time I checked, it wasn't recommended. Thanks

Comment: Grace is correct, it's still not recommend in 2018 due to e-mail client backwards compatibility. Professional bulk mail senders like MailChimp never use them.

Answer (score 2):

Hack on top of a hack.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="border-left: 20px solid white; border-right: 20px solid white; background: green; color: white; text-align: center;">
                This is stuff.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zy6GU/

Incidentally, the same thing should work with a `DIV`:

```
<div style="border-left: 20px solid white; border-right: 20px solid white; background: green; color: white; text-align: center;">This is a DIV.</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zy6GU/1/

Comment: awesome thanks, this works perfectly. I thought I had tried this one, but it kept messing up the rest of the content when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If you HAVE to use tables, might as well abuse them a little:

```
<table><tr align="center">
    <td width="50%">one</td>
    <td style="background-color:green">two</td>
    <td width="50%">three</td>
</tr></table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/yntfu/

Comment: Does that abuse have to include the use of deprecated and now unsupported (in HTML5) attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a CSS expert but this works for me (with no extra tags) :

```
<table>
  <tr style="background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;">
    <td style="background-color: green; display: block; margin: 0 20px;">
      <!-- Content -->
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

What are you talking about 'for emails'? You mean an email address, like `<a href="mailto:somewhere@domain.com">Email Me</a>`? If so you'd want some css that centers the link in the TD, or in combination with colspan on the TD.