# How to center the table data elements themselves in the row?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a table with the following layout for a time-sheet like application:

```
<table width="100%" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Function</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">(01)</td> <!-- 7 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Products</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">(02)</td> <!-- 10 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Other Codes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">V</td> <!-- 6 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

Each row has a different amount of table data elements. I'm trying to get the table data elements themselves centered in the entire row, not just the text inside the element itself but I cannot seem to find out how to do this.

Anything I've googled just gives me various things related to the `align` and `valign` attributes for the content of the cell itself, rather than centering the cells in the row.

I've tried messing around with the margin and border sizes but it doesn't seem to make any difference as recommended in some of these threads:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8649701/1189566

[How to align td elements in center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10675427/how-to-align-td-elements-in-center)

and a few other forums but haven't had any success.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use table elements, you could do a table within the table data and get something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/ykevsws0/

```
<table width="100%" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Function</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">(01)</td>
        <!-- 7 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Products</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">(02)</td>
        <!-- 10 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Other Codes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>V</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>V</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>V</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>V</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>V</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Another way to do it if for some reason you cannot manipulate the markup is use css to force table data to display:block, like this (might want to specify a css class or something, applying this style to td across the board will cause problems):
http://jsfiddle.net/jagsyguv/

```
<table width="100%" border="1px">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="11" align="center">Function</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">(01)</td>
            <!-- 7 more TD's after this -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="11" align="center">Products</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">(02)</td>
            <!-- 10 more TD's after this -->
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="11" align="center">Other Codes</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                V
            </td>
            <td>
                V
            </td >
            <td>
                V
            </td>
            <td>
                V
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a div. A div acts differently than a table, thus you can place it, with some style options, where you want in the page.

You can also build this table with just divs. I prefer using divs rather than tables, because they are easier to handle when you get used to them.

Try searching more info about divs and their usage.

This is a simple example:

```
<div style="margin:auto; width:60%; padding:10px;">
    <table style width="100%" border="1px">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Function</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">(01)</td> <!-- 7 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Products</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">(02)</td> <!-- 10 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="11" align="center">Other Codes</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center">V</td> <!-- 6 more TD's after this -->
    </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It helps to _explain_ your answer so that other users with similar (but not identical) problems can actually help themselves with your answer rather than try to copy/paste this without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need nested table for achieving this result

```html
<table width="100%" border="1px">
   <tr>
      <th colspan="11" align="center">Function</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="11" align="center">
         <table border="1px">
            <tr>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <td align="center">(01)</td>
               <!-- 7 more TD's after this -->
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th colspan="11" align="center">Products</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="11" align="center">
         <table border="1px">
            <tr>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <td align="center">(02)</td>
               <!-- 10 more TD's after this -->
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th colspan="11" align="center">Other Codes</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td colspan="11" align="center">
         <table border="1px">
            <tr>
               <td>V</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>V</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>V</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>V</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>V</td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Alternatively you could consider using css combined with div tags to generate the table / grid system

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to center elements in a `<td>` cell is the following. (This works for `<img>`, `<video>` and most other elements):

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="100%">
<tr>
<td>First Element</td>
<td>Second Element</td>
</tr>
</table>
```